# Need a sample implementation for AddRemoteScheme in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, f#

I have a back-end application (say API-A) which authenticates incoming requests using my custom-implemented IAM solution (say IAM-I). In essence, I pass a couple of tokens from the request headers to IAM-I which processes them and decides whether the request is authenticated or not.

I am trying to create a remote authentication scheme to invoke IAM-I from API-A. How do I create my own instance of `AuthenticationBuilder.AddRemoteScheme` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationOptions` to implement this?

I have written this:

```
iServiceCollection
     .AddAuthentication(fun options ->
          options.DefaultScheme          <- JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
          options.DefaultChallengeScheme <- JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddRemoteScheme("IAM-I Scheme", "IAM-I", remoteAuthAction)

let remoteAuthAction: Action<RemoteAuthenticationOptions> = new Action<RemoteAuthenticationOptions>(fun options ->
     ................ **TO BE FILLED** .................
);
```

Can someone help me figure out how to implement [RemoteAuthenticationOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.remoteauthenticationoptions?view=aspnetcore-2.2)? I couldn't find any example online.

The above snippet is in F# but I am okay with either F# or C#.

Comment: Did you find a sample?

Answer (score -1):

Are your IAM solution using JWT tokens?

JwtBearerDefaults only supports JWT-tokens and if your IAM solution uses OpenID Connect, then you should use AddJwtBearer to secure the API.